# How can I edit a picture like this one?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photography

[image]

I would like to achieve this blurry multiply image effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Adobe it should be easily accomplished in many different ways.

Alt. Click and drag would for sure be the easiest. It looks like there is a layer under the girls picture too. Add an image like the glittery background image as the background layer and arrange copies of the girl above it. If you need to, you can erase the background from the girls image leaving only her profile and transparent background. You could then play with opacity of the girls and layer blending to multiply or overlay. Really depends on the art you intend to use. Backgrounds and contrasts might keep you from simply copying and arranging layers with transparencies.

Youtube

Comment: Question has a photoshop tag.

Comment: Yeah I spaced out on that

Answer (score 2):

In photoshop you could use alt+drag to copy the image around and adjust the opacity of each copy (make sure to use different layers for each).

Comment: that was already said in another answer, check [answer] to learn more about the site.

Comment: I answered the question first. If you check the edit history, the accepted answer was edited later on.

Comment: oh indeed! my bad.